# Run javascript after Jquery Mobile Swipe Panel load

Tags: javascript, ajax

i am using Jquery Mobile (Open panel on swipe) and adding some attributes to the markup using JavaScript function code below

```
<?php if(Yii::app()->theme->name=='mobile'){ ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#merchants-grid').removeAttr('class');
$('#merchants-grid').children('table').attr('data-role','table').attr('id','table-   custom-2').attr('data-mode','columntoggle').attr('class','ui-body-d ui-shadow table-stripe ui-responsive').attr('data-column-btn-theme','b').attr('data-column-btn-text','display Column').attr('data-column-popup-theme','a').attr('cellpadding',1).attr('cellspacing',0);
$('#merchants-grid').children('table').children('thead').children('tr:first').addClass('ui-bar-d');
$('#merchants-grid').children('table').children('thead').children('tr:first').children('th').attr('data-priority',2);
});
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

but the javascript function not being included or being executed in the content

here is the markup

```
<div data-url="mob-top" data-role="page" id="mob-top" data-theme="d">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <a href="#mob-left-panel">
        Left Panel
    </a>
    <a href="#mob-right-panel">
        Right Panel
    </a>
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content">
      Content
</div><!-- /content -->
<div data-role="panel" id="mob-left-panel" data-theme="b">
    <a href="content">Left Panel Navigation</a>
</div><!-- /panel -->
<div data-role="panel" id="mob-right-panel" data-display="push" data-position="right" data-theme="c">
    <a href="content">Right Panel Navigation</a>
</div><!-- /panel -->
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using phonegap/cordova, you have to listen to "deviceready"

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

In normal browsers this should work if your selector is correct (not tested).